# ngClass-Angular with input and css

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

when the input variable is touched I would like it to change the css, but I'm having difficulties, when I click on the input it doesn't change the css, can anyone help me?
The idea would be that when the input was changed, the card would turn upside down with the css "hover"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwn2a.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYMGg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3n2e.png)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

One way to detect if input has been touched would be to use event callbacks (such as click listener on the form).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'input-clearable-example',
  templateUrl: './input-clearable-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-clearable-example.css'],
})
export class InputClearableExample {
  value = 'Clear me';
  isTouched: boolean = false;

  onTouch(event: any) {
    console.log(event)
    this.isTouched = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-form-field" appearance="fill" 
(click)="onTouch($event)" [ngClass]="{'background-red' : isTouched}">
  <mat-label>Touch me!</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="value"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

```css
.background-red {
background: red;
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-by3kvr-5wv7oo?file=src%2Fapp%2F.%2Finput-clearable-example.html

An even more correct way would be to actually check if the form has been `touched` https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-whether-a-form-or-a-control-is-touched-or-not-in-angular-10/